# Config ADFS / Spring Security to accept unsigned SAML AuthnRequest

Tags: spring-security, adfs, spring-saml

I'm trying to get my web app SAML-integrated with ADFS (it already works with other IdPs). The `AuthnRequest` that's sent to ADFS is unsigned. ADFS rejects the request, leaving this message in its log:

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.SignatureVerificationFailedException: MSIS0037: No signature verification certificate found for issuer 'com.onshape.saml2.sp'.

I've tried doing:

```
Set-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust -SignedSamlRequestsRequired $False
```

but that didn't help.

Can I configure ADFS to accept my app's unsigned requests? Or make some change to my app to make it generate requests that ADFS will accept?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is a bit misleading - the usual root cause is a mismatch between the issuer in your authentication request (`com.onshape.saml2.sp`) and the entity ID of the service provider you registered with ADFS.

Comment: Interesting idea but not applicable in my case, I think. The relevant bit of the `AuthnRequest` (extracted and decoded from the `SAMLRequest` URL query param in the `POST` request going to ADFS) is `<saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">com.onshape.saml2.sp</saml2:Issuer>`. The issuer in the request matches the value in the Relying Party trust in ADFS.